# How to create a Fusion chart with an external json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fusioncharts

I am new to Fusion charts. I can build a chart using jsonurl to the chart. like

```
var myChart = new FusionCharts( "FusionCharts/MSColumn3D.swf",
                "myChartId1", "400", "300", "0", "0" );
        myChart.setJSONUrl("resources/json/MSLine.json");
        myChart.render("chartContainer");
```

But i need to read the json using $getJson() or an ajax call and set the data. Because i want the chart dynamically. I can do all these for a single level fusion chart. like

```
var fChart = new FusionCharts(
      "./resources/js/fusion/Bar2D.swf",
      "BarChartId", "500", "300", "0");

    var jsonContent = new Object();
    var charts = new Object();
    //for chart properties..
    charts.palette = "1";
    charts.yaxisname = yaxisname;
    charts.xaxisname=xaxisname;
    charts.bgcolor = "406181, 6DA5DB";
    charts.bgalpha = "100";
    charts.basefontcolor = "FFFFFF";
    .
    .
    .  
    var datas = [];
    jQuery.each(data.Payload, function(index, value) {
        datas.push({
            label : value.label,
            value : value.value
        });
    });
    jsonContent.chart = charts;
    jsonContent.data = datas;

    fChart.setJSONData(jsonContent);
    fChart.render("chartContainer");
```

this is working fine, but for multiple series chart i didn't understand how the chart will getting the data. plz help me...

Comment: Not sure about the problem, Apart from creating the data which conform to FusionCharts' Multi series data format, everything else should be same. You need to study their Multi series data format and create similar JSON.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-series Column chart you need to create a `categories` array and add it to the `dataSource`

I have added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/q0m24kju/3/